# Забанят ли в GP за неофициальный клиент браузерной игры?

Tags: google-play

Есть браузерная онлайн-игра и официальный клиент, работающий на WebView. Если я напишу неофициальный клиент (нормальный, но работающий через парсинг) могут ли в GP забанить аккаунт? Честно говоря, уже боюсь что-либо туда выкладывать))

Comment: А кто им расскажет об этом? :)

Comment: @gil9red, ну мало ли...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну.. гарантировать что вас 100% не забанят никто не может, но можно предпринять ряд мер, чтобы этого избежать. Ну и лучше не использовать ключевые слова, которы могут давать хоть какую-то отсылку к той самой онлайн игре.
Много раз слышал что GP раздает баны не за плагиат как таковой, а за обращение в саппорт по поводу бана приложения :)

В общем если жалоба поступит от разрабов той игры, то приложение выпилят. А если будете уводить данные аккаунтов налево, то даже баном аккаунта можете не отделаться.